# How does curl differ to wget for authentication

Tags: curl, wget

What does curl do differently to wget? I am trying to access a secure webpage through the url using

```
https://username:password@website.com
```

However this doesn't seem to get me straight through to the page. If I try the same url with wget

```
wget https://username:password@website.com
```

I get an `ERROR 403: Forbidden`. If I try the same command with curl

```
curl https://username:password@website.com
```

The request is successful. What are the two commands doing differently? I would like to do whatever curl does, but from a browser url.

Comment: cURL defaults to [Basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), I don't know about wget. Is there any verbose flag that you can set in wget to see all the headers? With cURL you can use `-v`. If you find out with wget, do the same and compare the requests.

Comment: Yeah I tried the verbose command on curl (I just tried wget --verbose and it pretty much executes the request I gave above). It doesn't explicitly show me the url request. Is there a way to get around basic authentication with just the url?

Comment: Is there not a login dialog that pops up in the browser if you just use the url?

Comment: Yeah there is, but I would like to bypass it. I am trying to set up a webhook on a code repo using an existing plugin. The plugin doesn't have the option for authentication details so I am trying to hack my way around it through the url. Any suggestions beyond writing my own plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see which headers `wget` is sending by turning on debugging with `-d`.

```
wget -d https://username:password@website.com
```

You're interested in the bit between `--request begin--` and `--request end--`.  Here's an example for https://www.google.com

```
---request begin---
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.16.3 (darwin14.3.0)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: www.google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

For `curl`, use the verbose flag, `-v`.  You'll also want to send the content on STDOUT to /dev/null.

```
curl -v https://username:password@website.com > /dev/null.
```

You're interested in the lines with `>` at the start indicating they were sent by `curl`.  Again, here's https://www.google.com

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.44.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

`curl` will also give you information about the SSL negotiation.

---

One possibility is the web site has decided to bots by their User-Agent. It's possible they blocked `wget`, but forgot `curl`.  Try setting `wget --user-agent=curl/7.44.0 https://username:password@website.com` and see if that gets you in.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. So it looks like curl has an extra `Authorization: Basic d2F0NDIxOkF9ZXJ6MjAxNQ==` step. Is there a way to this with a url only request? P.S. Your sneaky `--user-agent` flag did not work.

Comment: @inJeans That means the server isn't properly sending an HTTP auth challenge. `curl` is sending your username and password *in the clear* using basic HTTP auth anyway. To avoid giving away your password, `wget` will only use basic auth if asked, even if you specify a username and password. Try `wget --auth-no-challenge`. Note that [basic HTTP auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is incredibly insecure and gives away your password. The server should, at minimum, be using [digest auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication).

Comment: That did seem to work. I should mention my ultimate goal is to do this in a browser url, so I would like to avoid solving the problem with wget commands if possible :-)

Comment: @inJeans Your browser is likely refusing to use basic HTTP auth as well.

Comment: So I guess I just have to deal with it?

Comment: @inJeans If you have the power, fix the server, or at least inform them they're sending passwords in the clear. Otherwise you might be able to configure the browser. What browser?

Comment: Cool. Thanks @Schwern. I might be able to contact sysadmin. I don't necessarily want to configure my browser as I am just trying to hack around a webhook plugin for stash.

Comment: @inJeans I'll amend what I said about passwords being sent in the clear. HTTPS encrypts the HTTP headers, which includes the basic auth header.  So at least the password cannot be sniffed. They still should be using digest auth anyway.